# Getting 10 quadratic squares a row

Tags: html, css

I want to have 10 quadratic squares each row, in this case by `10%`

However, with my current `stylesheet`, setting height to `10%` makes the squares disappear.

How do I achieve 10 quadratic squares a row?

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
}

.square {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="square red"></div>
    <div class="square blue"></div>
    <div class="square red"></div>
    <div class="square blue"></div>
    <div class="square red"></div>
    <div class="square blue"></div>
    <div class="square red"></div>
    <div class="square blue"></div>
    <div class="square red"></div>
    <div class="square blue"></div>

</div>
```

Here is the reproduced problem: http://jsfiddle.net/BLx8t/1/

Comment: I think you will need explicit pixel values to get "squares." The width and height are almost never the same, so relying on percentages will likely not work.

Comment: I'm not sure why but setting the height of the container clearly will fix your problem, also note that we can use the `nth-child` selector instead of creating 2 classes `red` and `blue` like you did, here is the edited fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BLx8t/10/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`height` spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property),

> **<percentage>**
>       Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. **If the
>   height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it
>   depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely
>   positioned, the value computes to 'auto'**. A percentage height on the
>   root element is relative to the initial containing block.

If you want them to be squares, you can use properties which (unlike `height`) are calculated relative to parent's width, like `margin` or `padding`:

- `margin` ([**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BLx8t/11/))

  ```
  .square:before {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      margin-top: 100%;
  }
  ```
- `padding` ([**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BLx8t/15/)), thanks @KingKing

  ```
  .square {
      padding-top: 10%;
  }
  ```

Comment: Also note you should add `#container { overflow: hidden; }` to clear floating. And you could use tabular displays to make it work independently of the number of squares: [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BLx8t/14/)

Comment: Based mostly on your idea, I made another version of fiddle in which we don't need any extra `:before` element, just setting the `padding-top:10%` right inside the `.square` and it also works :) http://jsfiddle.net/BLx8t/15/

Comment: @KingKing Thanks, I included it.

Comment: Well, even using just padding (no width and height) is also OK http://jsfiddle.net/BLx8t/16/

Comment: In fact, I'm still learning Web, your answer really helps me :)